# Converting latex to Html character problems

Tags: pandoc, html, quoting

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the nano text editor to create my .tex files.

When using quotations I use `\textquoteblleft` and `\textquoteblright`, otherwise if I use `"`, all of the quotes in the compiled pdf are right quotes.

I'm using Pandoc to convert my .tex into an .html, `pandoc -s -o file.html file.tex`. But when I do this the quotations don't show in the html file.
I also have this problem with em-dashes `\textemdash`

Is there a way to make the quotations and em-dashes compatible for both html and pdf?

Comment: never use `"` in tex input, to get quotes the traditional markup is `\`\`...''`  that is two backticks and two single quote/apostrophe  which then ligature to left and right double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle%3E)'s comment I found out that I can use two back ticks ``` `` ``` for the left quote and two sigle quotes`''` for the right quote and this will show up as quotations in html and pdf.

As for the em-dashes; after some experimenting I found that using three hyphens `---` will work for html and pdf.